# Is there a service for deploying application/program binaries (releases)?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration

Normally my code is stored on Bitbucket and built using some CI service like codeship. During build process new file is created for example "myapp-v1.2.3.zip" or "myapp-v0.0.1.exe" etc. From this point packages are deployed to FTP or directly to server or to S3 - generally to a place from which user can download them.

My question is if there exists service to store such code releases (specially dedicated for this purpose) - for example with public dashboard with all versions of myapp listed and available to download etc? And maybe simple API to check latest version, dev versions, stable version etc.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. You can add it as the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bintray is the software distribution service provided by JFrog, the makers of Artifactory.

https://bintray.com/